# Binding a list to a series of controls

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Im trying to make the children's game: [memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_%28game%29) in wpf, i have a list of "Tile" which has an image on them. I want to lay the Tiles out in my Board (also a class with a list of Tile). I need to make the control for layout and then lay it out in e.g. a 4 x 4 matrix.

How to I bind my List to an amount of controls (maybe buttons?) and spread them out on my board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx), bind its [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) to your list, make an [`ItemTemlate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) which contains a Button and set the [`ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) to something like a [`UniformGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx) or a [`WrapPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx).

Comment: Thanks it works, any idea on how im using a wrap panel now, any idea on how i can have a fixed amount of columns, so i can make like 4x4 tiles?

Comment: @H4mm3rHead: `WrapPanels` just take the available space and wrap items to the next row when space runs out, if you want a customizable grid then you should use the `UniformGrid` instead, it has properties which can set the row and column counts ([`Rows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.rows.aspx) & [`Columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.columns.aspx)).